# How to write all files found in one directory into one command line for calling an executable?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a directory with a bunch of files with a mix of extensions. I only want to work with files with extension `*.abc`. Each `*.abc` file should then be handed over to another software with some parameters. The parameters are always the same for each file. One of the parameters needs to be defined by the user, though.

So my first try was this:

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p value="Enter required imput value: "
for %%f in (*.abc) do (
    START C:\"Program Files"\Software\startsoftware.exe -parameter1 "%%~nf.abc" -parameter2 %value% -parameter3
)
PAUSE
```

The script works but is causing a memory crash, as the software is getting all request basically at once.

However, if I could manage to write all file names in one command line the software would process all files one by one. It needs to be called like this:

```
START C:\"Program Files"\Software\startsoftware.exe -parameter1 file1.abc -parameter2 %value% -parameter3 -parameter1 file2.abc -parameter2 %value% -parameter3 -parameter1 file3.abc -parameter2 %value% -parameter3 -parameter1 file4.abc -parameter2 %value% -parameter3
```

My idea was to generate a `files.txt` with listing all `*.abc` using:

```
dir /b /a-d > files.txt
```

Then read that list into my command. However, I don't know how to read out the `files.txt` and apply parameters including the variable `%value%` to each file.

Comment: But there is a physical command line execution limitation of 8,191 bytes.  I can see that line easily maxing out trying to do what you are doing.  Have you tried just **not** using the `START` command.  That is probably why you are running out of memory because you are running them synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Quote inside an argument string

`"` inside an argument string is usually not correct. The entire argument string must be usually enclosed in double quotes and not just parts of it. So wrong is `C:\"Program Files"\Software\startsoftware.exe` and correct would be `"C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe"`.

That can be seen by opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), typing `C:\Prog` and hitting key <kbd>TAB</kbd> to let Windows command processor complete the path to `"C:\Program Files"`. The Windows command processor added automatically the required double quotes around entire path string. The path would change to `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` on pressing once more key <kbd>TAB</kbd>. However, continue typing with `"C:\Program Files"` displayed by entering `\soft` and press again <kbd>TAB</kbd> and displayed is `"C:\Program Files\Software"`. The second `"` moved to end of new path. Type next `\start` and press once more <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Now is displayed `"C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe"` which is the correct fully qualified file name of this executable enclosed in double quotes as required because of the space character in path.

For more information about this feature of Windows command processor run in command prompt window `cmd /?` and read the output help from top of first page to bottom of last page.

### 2. START and TITLE string

The help for command **START** is output on running `start /?` in a command prompt window.

**START** interprets the first double quoted string as optional title string for the console window. For that reason it is advisable to specify first after command name **START** always a title in double quotes. In case of a Windows GUI application is started on which no console window is opened at all or a console application is executed in background without opening a new console window, the title string can be specified with just `""` after **START** which is just an empty title string.

### 3. Running applications parallel

The command **START** is used to run an application or script parallel to the Windows command process which is processing the batch file. This is often useful, but definitely not here on which an application should be executed to process a file of a large set of files which need to be processed all.

The following command line would start for each *.abc file the executable `startsoftware.exe` for execution parallel to `cmd.exe` which is processing the batch file.

```
for %%f in (*.abc) do START "" "C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe" -parameter1 "%%~nf.abc" -parameter2 %value% -parameter3
```

This results with many *.abc files in current directory in a situation on which Windows fails to run one more process due to a resource problem as too many processes are running already more or less parallel.

### 4. Running application in series

It is usually better on processing many files to run an application for processing a file and halt processing of the batch file until the application finished and terminated itself. That can be achieved by not using the command **START**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist *.abc (
    echo ERROR: There are no *.abc in folder: "%CD%"
    echo(
    pause
    exit /B
)
set "Value="
:UserPrompt
set /P "Value=Enter required input value: "
if not defined Value goto UserPrompt
set "Value=%Value:"=%"
if not defined Value goto UserPrompt
for %%I in (*.abc) do "C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe" -parameter1 "%%I" -parameter2 "%Value%" -parameter3
endlocal
```

The behavior on starting an executable from within a batch file is different to doing that from within a command prompt window. The Windows command processor waits for the self-termination of the started executable on being started during processing of a batch file. Therefore this code runs always just one instance of `startsoftware.exe` in comparison to the loop above using command **START** to start multiple instances quickly in a short time.

### 5. Running application with multiple files

It looks like it is possible to run `startsoftware.exe` with multiple arguments to process several files at once. But the maximum command line length limit of 8191 characters must be taken into account on writing a batch file which runs the executable with a list of arguments to process multiple files at once.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist *.abc (
    echo ERROR: There are no *.abc in folder: "%CD%"
    echo(
    pause
    exit /B
)
set "Value="
:UserPrompt
set /P "Value=Enter required input value: "
if not defined Value goto UserPrompt
set "Value=%Value:"=%"
if not defined Value goto UserPrompt

set "Arguments="
set "CmdLineLimit="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.abc /A-D /B 2^>nul') do call :AppendFile "%%I"
if defined Arguments "C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe"%Arguments%
exit /B

:AppendFile
set Arguments=%Arguments% -parameter1 %1 -parameter2 "%Value%" -parameter3
set "CmdLineLimit=%Arguments:~7800,1%"
if not defined CmdLineLimit goto :EOF
"C:\Program Files\Software\startsoftware.exe"%Arguments%
set "Arguments="
set "CmdLineLimit="
goto :EOF
```

The loop `for %%f in (*.abc) do` is modified in this code to a `for /F` loop to get first a list of file names loaded completely into memory instead of processing the directory entries which could change on each execution of `startsoftware.exe` if it modifies the *.abc files in current directory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also: [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)