# How do I create a bat file to process different file names within a directory?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

How do I create a bat file to process different files within a directory? The file names are incrementing as below and the command that I need in the bat file should be something like **java -jar Test.jar (the incrementing file names)** one after the other. I have create one .bat file which looks like this -

```
java -jar Test.jar TESTDOC1.xml 
java -jar Test.jar TESTDOC2.xml
java -jar Test.jar TESTDOC3.xml

pause
```

But there is a possibility that the count might increase to a huge number.

**File Names:**

```
TESTDOC1.xml TESTDOC2.xml TESTDOC3.xml
```

how do I do it?

Comment: with the usage of a `for` loop and wildcard `*`. open cmd.exe and enter `For /?` for more information

Comment: Seems like it would be better to change your JAVA program to use a wildcard to read the files from the directory.  The reason I say that is because cmd.exe has a line limit of 8,192 bytes.  If you have hundreds of XML files that you need to process, the command line execution could easily exceed that.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks. What if I redirect the output to a simple .txt file. The challenge that I have here is that I am not supposed to edit the java program but instead create a .bat file to feed the files to the jar file.

Comment: @TWEET Take a look on my answer on [write all files found in one directory into one command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359278/3074564)

Comment: I guess I need to understand why they all need to be on the same line for execution.  Why couldn't you just loop through the file names and keep executing java?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are really incremented by numbers like you say, why not just:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('dir testdoc*.xml ^| findstr "File(s)"') do (
   for /l %%a in (1,1,%%i) do echo java -jar test.jar testdoc%%a.xml
)
```

Where I have `echo` to simply print to screen, you need to remove `echo` if the printed results are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and it worked. Thanks Squashman for the help

```
for /r %%i in (*.xml) do java -jar Test.jar %%i >myopt.txt
pause
```